# Is it possible to execute functions in a hosted php file from android/java?

Tags: java, php, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an amazon web services MySql database that I want to perform CRUD operations on from an android application. I think that the way to do this is through some HTTP protocol and get and post operations. However, I have access to PHP code that connects to the database and allows me to execute quires. This PHP code is hosted on an elastic beanstalk application. Someone else has used this same code to connect the database to IOS. I am just trying to figure out how it all works.

Is it possible to use the PHP that is hosted to act as an API for me?

--I cant post any links due to security concerns, sorry.--

Comment: android can't execute php, unless you manage to find a complete php interpreter build for android and manage to get it installed on your device. android **CAN** invoke php via http, but that applies to ANY language that can service an http request.

Comment: Look up what a webservice is and how to write one.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make a REST call to an HTTP endpoint from your Android device, then yes, the PHP can act as an API. 
Consider using the AWS API Gateway as the piece of 'glue' that you are missing, though its not required.

Answer (score 0):

I had some friends help me and what I seem to have on my hands is an API that uses no sort of authentication. It is not restful because no token is returned and it does not implement sessions either. From what I understand, each hosted PHP file can be access via respective HTTP request.

[E.J. Brennan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53686/e-j-brennan) proposed adding an instance of AWS API Gateway that I believe to be the next step.